# Which is more appropriate, "contest," "contestation," or a different word?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, synonyms, phrase-requests

I'm in the process of submitting a request for a late assignment's grade to be re-evaluated. Is it more appropriate to use the word "contest," "contestation," or another word in this context? For example, one would refer to the situation as a "late assignment contestation" if that was the appropriate word. I feel that "late assignment contest" doesn't seem appropriate, since to me that would connote some kind of sporting event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aren't you looking for [appeal](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/appeal) (MW, definition 2a)

> an application (as to a recognized authority) for corroboration, vindication, or decision

You could use it as follows:

> I want to appeal this grade.
>
> I am filing an appeal to have the grade for my late assignment revised.
>
> I appealed to the Dean to have my failing grade reconsidered.

Comment: 'Appeal' could work, though after looking for similar words, I think 'petition' may better suit this situation. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I was going to suggest "dispute" but "appeal" is clear and less aggressive, perhaps inviting a better response.